# Fallo en syntaxis

Tags: mysql

Pues el tipico fallo de foreing key, el problema es que no lo veo y nunca se ver el por que salta el fallo, esta es mi tabla, el fallo es el siguiente(aunque con solo ver la tabla ya sabréis cual es):

13:47:25    ALTER TABLE Proveedores ADD FOREIGN KEY (Nombre_producto) REFERENCES Productos(Codigo) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `productos`.`proveedores` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")  0.047 sec

```
CREATE DATABASE Productos;

USE Productos;


Create table Productos(
Codigo VARCHAR(40)NOT NULL,
Nombre VARCHAR(40),
Precio FLOAT
);


Create table Proveedores(
NIF VARCHAR(40)NOT NULL,
Nombre VARCHAR(40),
Direccion VARCHAR(40),
Nombre_producto VARCHAR(40)
);

ALTER TABLE Proveedores
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Nombre_producto) REFERENCES Productos (Codigo)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE;


Create table Clientes(
DNI VARCHAR(40)NOT NULL,
Nombre VARCHAR(40),
Apellidos VARCHAR(40),
Direccion VARCHAR(40),
Fecha_de_nacimiento DATE
);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! REcuerda aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron!

Answer (score 0):

Como no puedes crear una clave ajena referenciada a un campo no indexado, debes ejecutar antes esta instrucción:

```
ALTER TABLE Productos ADD INDEX(Codigo);
```

Aunque igual `Codigo` debería haber sido clave principal, con que al menos sea un índice, vale.

Comment: A joder vale si me acabode dar cuenta gracias